# Копирование текста Python

Tags: python

Есть файл с текстом. Нужно найти в нём все слова, которые содержат указанные буквы, и записать эти слова в другой файл.

Пример:
Файл file.txt:

```
Перечень мебели Стул Стол шкаф и тд
```

Искомые буквы:

```
е, о, ф
```

Записать в файл result.txt:

```
Перечень, мебели, Стол, шкаф
```

Есть идеи, как это можно реализовать без использования каких-либо модулей?

Comment: Смотря какой текст. Ведь сначала в нём нужно идентифицировать слова. А это довольно сложная задача. Можете привести какой-нибудь пример?

Comment: Перечень мебели
Стул
Стол
шкаф
и тд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой, на мой взгляд, вариант в использовании проверки с `in`:

```
answer = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        if 'а' in line:
            answer.append(line)
    else:
        break
print(' '.join(answer))
```

При необходимости можно расширить сами подстроки или их количество при помощи `or`
А вообще для более углубленного поиска советую ознакомиться с регулярными выражениями и библиотекой `re`

Comment: у вас через инпут, а если уже есть файл и из него нужно записать в другой? создав другой

Comment: Тогда `f = open('text.txt')` и вместо бесконечного цикла `for line in f:`

Answer (score 1):

```
CHARS = "еоф"

with open("file.txt") as inp, open("result.txt", "w") as out:
    for word in inp.read().split():
        if any(char in word for char in CHARS):
            out.write(word + "\n")
```

---

`result.txt`:

> ```
> Перечень
> мебели
> Стол
> шкаф
> ```

---

*Примечание:* Для вывода слов в *единую строку* замените `"\n"` за `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете с помощью приведения слов к множеству проверять наличие в них букв, а потом, используя регулярные выражения, убирать знаки препинания, которые "приклеились" к словам.
Я для проверки брал текст прямо в программе, а результат выводил в консоль. Вам же нужно раскомментировать чтение и запись, поменять название исходного и результирующего файла и убрать текст, записанный вручную.

```py
# Чтение из файла filename.txt
#with open("filename.txt") as f:
#    text = f.read()

text = """Жили у бабуси
Два весёлых гуся,
Один - серый, другой - белый,
Два весёлых гуся.
Один - серый, другой - белый,
Два весёлых гуся!""" # текст, в котором ищем слова

letters = 'бгу' # буквы, слова с которыми ищем (только маленькие буквы)
temporary = (
    word # слово
    for word in text.split() # из текста, разбитого по пробелам
    if set(word.lower()) & set(letters) # если у слова есть хотя бы одна из искомых букв
) # Временный результат - к словам могли приклеиться знаки препинания

result = [
    word.strip(",.;:-!?") # слово без знаков препинания (если возможны другие знаки - добавить их сюда)
    for word in temporary # из списка подходящих нам слов
]

print(result) # все подходящие слова
print(set(result)) # подходящие слова, но без повторений (ПОРЯДОК СЛОВ НЕ СОХРАНЯЕТСЯ)

# Запись в файл result_filename.txt
#with open("result_filename.txt", "w") as f:
#    f.write(', '.join(result)) # либо f.write(', '.join(set(result))), если нужны без повторений
```

Преимущество метода приведения строки к множеству заключается в удобстве поиска большого количества букв. Вы можете добавить столько искомых букв в `letters`, сколько вам нужно

Comment: без дополнительных модулей нужно

Comment: @Alex обновил решение. Теперь оно чуть менее гибкое, но не использует модуль `re`

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = set('буквы')
with open('in.txt') as f:
    words = set(word for line in f for word in line.split())
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(w for w in words if letters & set(w)))
```